# How to visualize graphson data?

Tags: gremlin, graphson

i got a requirement to build a Graphson format for the provided data, i'm all done performing that, now my question is, how do i visualize the graphson the way we do that in yEd for graphml. A) Is there any tool to perform that? B) If not, then is there any changes do i need to make to visualize it in any tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GraphSON, then you can just read it into a TinkerGraph and write it out as GraphML.

```
Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph("tinkerpop-modern.json");
graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).writeGraph("tinkerpop-modern.xml")
```

Comment: I think you have them reversed, What you wrote is reading GraphMl and writing GraphSON. You want to readGraph the GraphSON file and writeGraph the GraphML file.